VBA Adding Spaces to Numbers Populated from Range to Array
When populating an Excel range to an array, the numbers in the range gets spaces on either side of them after it is inside the array.
I am populating the range shown below to an array using the following line of code. But the numbers populated into the array has a space on either side. Due to this I am unable to match these numbers with other ranges.
arrRng = shtCalc.Range("F7:J12")





trim?

I believe that's just an artifact of the Immediate Window: https://i.sstatic.net/Jpkn7xM2.png. arr(1,3) is still a Double.

Format the range using NumberFormat = "0" ?

@BigBen is correct. You'd see the same thing with just ?12345 in the Immediate window

...not for non-number output though: that doesn't get the extra space prepended.

And negative numbers have no prepended space.
